# Error in my code in python 3 (coin change problem)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the error:

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
           34      
    count      25      
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

The code can be found here:

```
import sys

N = int(sys.stdin.readline()) #4

munten = []                   #1, 2, 5, 10

for p in range(0, N):
    munten.append(sys.stdin.readline())

bedrag = int(sys.stdin.readline()) #13

m = len(munten)


def count(S, m, bedrag):

    table = [[0 for x in range(m)] for x in range(bedrag+1)]

    for i in range(m):
        table[0][i] = 1

    for i in range(1, bedrag+1):
        for j in range(m):

            x = table[i - S[j]][j] if i-S[j] >= 0 else 0

            y = table[i][j-1] if j >= 1 else 0

            table[i][j] = x + y

    return table[bedrag][m-1]


print(count(munten, m, bedrag)) #output = 16
```

The inputs: N = 4 (amount of coins in array), (the array) munten = (1, 2, 5, 10), (amount to pay) bedrag = 13 --> (amount of combinations I can pay with the coins in the array) output = 16

Comment: The error indicates that you're trying to perform subtraction using a string. Check your code wherever you use the `-` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`munten` are list of strings in your code.

```
for p in range(0, N):
    munten.append(int(sys.stdin.readline()))
```

Execution example

```
> python3 sample.py
> 4  #N
> 1  #munten0
> 2  #munten1
> 5  #munten2
> 10 #munten3
> 13 #bedrag 
16
```